# Session replication in Glassfish Cluster on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, glassfish-3, session-cookies, sessionid

I've built a cluster on Glassfish administred via SSH, where there are 2 instances. I deployed an application that shows the "Session id".

This application has in the web.config:

```
<distributable/>
```

And in the sun-web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-properties>
         <property name="cookieDomain" value="compute.amazonaws.com"/>
    </cookie-properties>
</session-config>
```

I enabled "Availability" in Edit Application.

But when I access the 2 web app versions I see different session ids.
Can anyone help me?

EDIT: As some users noticed, in EC2 is not supported multicast. A solution comes with Glassfish v3.1.2, that allows two other different ways to discover a cluster when multicasting is not permitted (by listing instances ip or making it auto-generate the list). Here's specified how to start a cluster in a non-multicasting environment: [Administering Glassfish Server Clusters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24934/clusters.htm#CHDGAIBJ)

Comment: AFAIK the glassfish underlying cluster infrastructure, schoal, **does not support unicast**, only multicast, which is not supported natively on EC2 or VPC, making session synchronization not viable, but I don't have deep knowledge on the subject.

Comment: I found resources saying that is possible, but I'm still working on it. Hope to be able to update soon, thanks. Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some users noticed, in EC2 is not supported multicast. A solution comes with Glassfish v3.1.2, that allows two other different ways to discover a cluster when multicasting is not permitted (by listing instances ip or making it auto-generate the list). Here's specified how to start a cluster in a non-multicasting environment: [Administering Glassfish Server Clusters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24934/clusters.htm#CHDGAIBJ)

Comment: Do you actually need the cookie settings in glassfish-web.xml (or sun-web.xml)? I tried following this and the front end app that was set up to run with a single non-clustered instance failed. It worked in that setup, but no-one had created a glassfish-web.xml file or named the cookies. If you name the cookie in this file will the front end people have to look for a different cookie name in their app? If you leave this file and cookie settings out, will it still create a session cookie (if declared in the java code)?

Answer (score 2):

Read the High Availability Administration Guide for v3.1.2, specifically section "Discovering a Cluster When Multicast Transport Is Unavailable". Haven't tried it yet, but looking forward. Cheers!

Comment: I'm also following the steps suggested in [this doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24934/clusters.htm#CHDGAIBJ), hope to update soon the question. Thanks, A.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to try would be trying to validate if the multicast works on your your setup, use below asadmin command.

```
asadmin validate-multicast
```

You can checkout this simple Youtube Video about how to do that

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJTDao9OpWA

In case Multicast does not work, you may want to try the non multicast option that is supported on Recent release of [Glassfish 3.1.2](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/entry/glassfish_3_1_2_released)

The release notes say that it supports non multicast clustering

> New Support for non-Multicast clustering.  GlassFish High-Availability
>   clustering is now possible in environments where multicast is
>   disabled.

I was not able to find any documentation that provides steps for setting up the non Multicast cluster. There may be one for the enterprise support customers.

Comment: It is possible, you're right. Here is how to do that: [Administering Glassfish].(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24934/clusters.htm#CHDGAIBJ)