# Glassfish Cluster Session Problems On Amazon EC2 Using Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: session, amazon-ec2, glassfish, cluster-computing, servlet-filters

First this app works perfectly fine in a non-clustered environment.

The problem we have is when the ELB routes first to one server in a cluster during a session, then to a second server. The second server can't find the session. e.g.

1. An iOS app passes a login call to a Glassfish 4 server cluster (we're using oAuth/Facebook tokens, so no Glassish security realms).
2. The Amazon Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) sends to server 1.
3. Session is authenticated and user logged in and a session cookie passed back to the app.
4. Immediately the app sends another request which needs authentication (is this a valid session).
5. The ELB decides to send the request to server 2
6. In our authenticate servlet filter, server 2 can't find a session with the id passed in with the cookie
7. The servlet says the user is not authenticated and the call fails.

Our code is pretty typical for finding the session (if no session immediately return fail):

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
//psuedocode
if session == null then session not authenticated log and return
else session authenticated, log and return
```

If the second call gets routed to the same server as the login, the second call works fine. Whenever a call (be it the second, third, fourth, whatever) goes to the second server, authentication fails because it can't find the session on the second server.

I'm looking to see if anyone has encountered something like this and how you have resolved the issue. Is it better to use sticky sessions on the ELB, or is Apache web server using JK or AJP a better choice?

Answer (score 0):

Two potential issues off the top of my head:

1. Have you specified `<distributable/>` in your web.xml?
2. Could be a multicast issue. EC2 does not support multicast, which is what GlassFish uses by default. Check out [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198974/session-replication-in-glassfish-cluster-on-ec2) that discusses the topic, including non-multicast clustering.

Comment: distributable is in the web.xml and I have set up non-multicasting clustering

Comment: I noticed an interesting comment on this web page: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2426/abdla.html Note - When using high availability session persistence together with a load balancer, use a load balancer that includes session-based stickiness as part of its load-balancing algorithm. Otherwise, session data can be misdirected or lost. An example of a load balancer that includes session-based stickiness is the Loadbalancer Plug-In available in Oracle GlassFish Server.

Comment: do you see any issue with accessing the second server in a non-failover scenario? The only reason the second server is being hit is because of the ELBs round robin implementation. Should the second server still be able to return a reference to the session. Our app is just trying to find the same session id as is in the session cookie, but when we make the call in my post we get 'null' for the session. I see a JREPLICA cookie created when initially logging in on the first server where the session is created. So I'm wondering if it is a 'how we're trying to get the session' issue.

Comment: Yes, you want to use an LB with session stickiness, which is supported (http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/).  You should be able to access multiple instances in a non-failover scenario as well.  Note that we do not test ELB at all, but others do have it running although it's not clear to me if that is stateless or with replication enabled.

Comment: We *think* this is a timing issues. i.e. The session isn't being propagated as fast as we are looking for it on another instance. We created a test harness client that retries when session comes up null and on a second or third call to the server we find the session. We first tried just looping on the request#getSession(null) call, but we finally figured out we actually have to send in another call to pick up the server side session object. Now we are having some other issues, but not sure yet if they are session related or our own (getting user data from the db using session data keys).